# Using build parameters in Jenkins without quotes

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins. Using build parameters such as

```
test=my string
```

then using that

```
${test}  gives 'my string'
```

the result is quoted.

How can I NOT have the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put quotes arround the variable in the shell command.

```
"${test}"
```