# How to correctly parse build parameters in Jenkins running on Linux when receiving a string with spaces and double quotes?

Tags: linux, variables, jenkins, environment, single-quotes

I configured a parametrized Jenkins Job build which takes the following argument called "testcases":

`-t "Can Get Fake Name" -t "Can call Password"`

This is a string that has to be passed via command line to the robot framework executable.

Jenkins is running on Linux (Centos 7) and this is the build script I wrote to achieve my target:

```sh
robot "${testcases}" myrobottest.robot
```

I have found the `${testcases}` suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550568/using-build-parameters-in-jenkins-without-quotes) which is partially solving my issue.

The result command on Jenkins is as it follows:

```sh
+ robot '-t "Can Get Fake Name" -t "Can call Password"' myrobottest.robot
[ ERROR ] Suite 'myrobottest' contains no tests named ' "Can Get Fake Name" -t "Can call Password"'.
```

The problem here are the trailing single-quotes that I don't know how to remove (or to not produce).

Before using the `${testcases}` notation I also tried to use the environment variable like `$testcases` but it produces something with many useless single-quotes.

Any suggestion please?

I expect the generated command line to be

```sh
robot -t "Can Get Fake Name" -t "Can call Password" myrobottest.robot
```

but actual output is:

```sh
robot '-t "Can Get Fake Name" -t "Can call Password"' myrobottest.robot
```

**EDIT**

I did one more attempt.
If I change the script line as below:

```sh
eval echo robot \${testcases} docker-robot-framework.robot
```

I get the following console output.

```sh
+ eval echo robot '${testcases}' myrobottest.robot
++ echo robot -t '"Can' Get Fake 'Name"' myrobottest.robot
robot -t "Can Get Fake Name" myrobottest.robot
```

I think I'm close to the solution, because I only have to execute such `eval` expression (that is correct by the way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved doing the following way:

```sh
/bin/sh -c "robot $testcases myrobottest.robot"
```

Actually, the resulting command line that is executed is correct now, and working:

```sh
/bin/sh -c 'robot -t "Can Get Fake Name" -t "Can call Password" myrobottest.robot'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the `"` around `${testcases}`

```
IFS=$'\n'

robot ${testcases} myrobottest.robot
```

Comment: If I do this, the resulting command equals to this:
`robot -t '"Can' Get Fake 'Name"' -t '"Can' call 'Password"' myrobottest.robot`
As you may see, there are many single-quotes causing incorrect command line

Comment: Can you give a try after add `IFS=$'\n'`